# Is there are way to say if all of the conditions are true, else

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows Forms:  Is there a way to say if all of the following conditons are true then 'do this', otherwise 'do this'?  My form has multiple textboxes and at at least one of them needs to have something entered into it.  The code I have below checks for empty textboxes, but if ANY of the textboxes are empty then it sets the condition to false.

```
private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool allempty = true;
    foreach (Control d in Controls)
    {
        if (d is TextBox)
        { 
            TextBox textbox = d as TextBox;
            if (textbox.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                allempty = false; 
            }
        }
    }
    if (allempty == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Textboxes are all empty");
    }
    else
    {
        //Data entry code
        MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused by the variable naming and the code result. Is it working as expected ?

Comment: I still can't get it to work, but I'm working on it.  If one textbox has something in it, the 'Textboxes are all empty' still gets dispalyed.

Comment: I would replace textbox.Text == string.Empty by textbox.Text != string.Empty, then replace if (allempty == false) by if (allempty == true). The solutions in LINQ are better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 or above you could use linq and do something like this:

```
    private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(tb => String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Textboxes are all empty");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just use `Any` (or `All`, depending on which is appropriate for you) from LINQ:

```
if(Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
        .Any(textbox => textbox.Text == ""))
    MessageBox.Show("Textboxes are all empty");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Entry Added");
```

Comment: Is not it a bit strange to check if at least one checkbox is empty, then if true to display "Textboxes are all empty" ?

Comment: @Laurent Yes, it is strange, but as it's not clear if the error is in the wording of the text or the function of the code, I choose to keep it functionally equivalent to the OP's code.  Because of the inconsistency though I included the note about the `All` method, which could be used if that is the desirable behavior.

Comment: Understood, but it makes my eyes bleeding.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => x.Text == ""))
    // at least one is empty
```

Though from your variables names it seems that you need:

```
if(Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => x.Text != ""))
    // at least one isn't empty
```

Or:

```
if(Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(x => x.Text == ""))
    // all are empty
```